# Как сложить два массива по модулю с помощью LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Проще говоря, сложить массивы в двойном цикле. 
Допустим, есть массив {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} и {1, 2}. Складываем, получаем {2, 4, 4, 6, 6}
Подумал, что можно сделать это с LINQ, но не знаю как :)

Comment: У вас сложение массивов получается некоммутативным. При правильном сложении должно получиться {2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 3, 3, 5, 5, 7}

Comment: Рассматриваем массивы не как матрицы, а как набор чисел. И результат должен быть таким, как я хочу :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int[] arr1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; // {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
int[] arr2 = {1, 2}; // {1, 2}
int[] sumArr12 = arr1.Select((value, index) => value + arr2[index % arr2.Length]).ToArray(); // {2, 4, 4, 6, 6}
```

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант - можно воспользоваться Linq-операцией `Zip`, но т.к. массивы разной длины - давайте "зациклим" короткий массив:

```
static IEnumerable<T> Looped<T>(T[] array)
{
    for (int i = 0; ; i = (i + 1) % array.Length)
        yield return array[i];
}
```

Используем:

```
int[] ar1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int[] ar2 = { 1, 2 };
var ar3 = ar1.Zip(Looped(ar2), (x, y) => x + y).ToArray();
```

Comment: Вместо `Looped` можно сделать `Enumerable.Repeat(0, arr1.Length).SelectMany(_ => arr2).take(arr1.Length)`

Answer (score 1):

Насколько мне известно, то чистый LINQ тут не поможет. Такого функционала я не встречал. Могу предложить вариант, без использования LINQ, но вполне рабочий, с учетом размерностей массивов.

```
int[] arrOne = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; 
int[] arrTwo = { 1, 2 };          

int[] result = new int [arrOne.Length > arrTwo.Length ? arrOne.Length : arrTwo.Length];
var firstIndex = 0;
var secondIndex = 0;

for(int index = 0; index < result.Length; index++)
{
    firstIndex = arrOne.Length > firstIndex ? firstIndex : 0;
    secondIndex = arrTwo.Length > secondIndex ? secondIndex : 0;
    result[index] = arrOne[firstIndex++] + arrTwo[secondIndex++];
}

//result = {2, 4, 4, 6, 6}
```

Для наглядности примера этот же код на исходных значениях:

```
int[] arrOne = { 1, 2, 3 };  
int[] arrTwo = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
```

даст результат: `{ 2, 4, 6, 5, 7, 9 }`

Смысл кода прост, для начала сделаем массив `result` с размерностью бОльшего массива. Затем в обычном цикле `for` пройдем по созданному массиву и заполним его значения. Для чего `firstIndex` и `secondIndex` - это индексаторы первого и второго массивов соответсвенно. В чем смысл отдельных индексаторов - в том, чтобы начинать нумерацию с нуля, когда элементы в массиве закончились. Для такой задачи я не особо вижу смысл в использовании LINQ (в силу своей спецэфичности, вам написали в комментарии: *сложение массивов получается некоммутативным*).